# How to double click a div in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, bdd, chrome-web-driver

In a behave step implementation I wish to double click a div using webdriver. However I cannot get this to occur. My code:

```
@when('i double click on the element "{text}"')
def step_impl(context, text):
    action = webdriver.ActionChains(context.browser)
    action.double_click(context.browser.find_element_by_css_selector(text)).perform()
```

I have also tried

```
@when('i double click on the element "{text}"')
def step_impl(context, text):
    action = webdriver.ActionChains(context.browser)
    el = context.browser.find_element_by_css_selector(text)
    action.move_to_element_with_offset(el, 10, 10).double_click()
    action.perform()
```

the `find_element_by_css_selector` returns a `WebElement` as expected. But the `double_click` javascript action is never performed - a new div should appear - failing silently in the scenario steps.

Comment: It is there at the end of the double_click call?

Comment: Oops, didn't see that...

Comment: May be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870528/double-clicking-in-python-selenium#20697848