# Selenium preform double click + text edit using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, automation

I want to automate *canva.com* site, using python's selenium library.

What I need to do ?

I need to insert data to fields inside canva (very simple). To force canva save my changes I need firstly DoubleClick the element, and only then update the text.

What is my problem ?

After I double click the element, it's changing ... and I can't change that *python* element's text. to change it, I need to find that element again and only than change it. - I Got an error that the element is not attached to the page.

```py
def get_report_params_fields(driver, keys):
    fields = {}

    all_paragraphs = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("p")

    for paragraph in all_paragraphs:
        key = re.sub(' +', ' ', paragraph.text.upper()).split(":")[0]
        if key in keys:
            if key in fields.keys():
                fields[key].append(paragraph)
            else:
                fields[key] = [paragraph]

    return fields

# update fields list
canva_fields = get_report_params_fields(driver)

# click the field to change 
canva_fields[canva_key][task_index].click()
canva_fields[canva_key][task_index].click()

# update fields list
canva_fields = get_report_params_fields(driver)

# update the data 
value = key + ": " + keys[key]

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].textContent = arguments[1];", canva_fields[canva_key][task_index], value)
```

The problem is that the `get_report_params_fields` (which just goes over all the paragraphs on the page and select the one I need) function is not efficient, so I want to use it only once.

So I am searching for a way to get the webelement I click using another way (using it's xpath, location, some other unique id of the webelement). I mean I need an option to find the same element again using the webelement properties, Without known the properties before (like checking the xpath in chrome, and I can't use the element's text because it is changing from time to time).

I thought about double clicking and changing the text inside oneliner javascript script, but I didn't found a way to do that.

Comment: Can you please share the html of the element before dbl click and after dbl click.  Seems to be we need the login details to access the elements that you are trageting.

Comment: [This answer could be what you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20697848/1183506). Essentially using Actions to string your clicks and possibly text entry together. If the page changes though (`Element not attached to page`), you might need to stop right before that happens and find the element again.

Comment: did you try using Actions for double click and then send a text? In case you didn't give it a try should work and resolve the issue. below is the code for double click using actions.                                                        


Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement elementLocator = driver.findElement(By.id("ID"));
actions.doubleClick(elementLocator).perform();

Comment: @supputuri 
the elements are exactly the same
`<p style="line-height: 1.4; font-family: &quot;YALBs6uSPpE 0&quot;, _fb_, auto; font-size: 8.71953px; text-transform: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" class="direction-ltr align-start para-style-subtitle"><strong style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-decoration: none;">http://domain_0</strong></p>`

Comment: @KrunalPatel 
not Worked :( the same error

Comment: @MeirTolpin Which line of code gives you the error? The first click? second click? When you try to do something after the double click? The abstract approach here would be to wait for some condition on the page to indicate it has stopped changing, and then you can find the elements again. I could provide more detail if you can indicate which line of code gives you the error... And if you know it, what the html is of an element before and after the change.

Comment: I know you'd like to use javascript, but in this case I think you can get a more simple solution by optimizing `get_report_params_fields` and waiting properly