# I've just started learning web scraping using selenium. I need to login a local website and double click on some items

Tags: python, selenium

I need to login a local website and double click on some items. I could log into it but I can't find the code to double click on items
[image]

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870528/double-clicking-in-python-selenium

Comment: actually I want to double click on the folder which is named '9908':

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the html code of the local website.

Comment: share the link of the web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the element by `link_text`, then double click the element using `ActionChains` as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20697848/12309808):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

folder = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '9908')]")
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
actionChains.double_click(folder).perform()
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"9908"}

Comment: Try adding a `time.sleep` before finding the element. If that doesn't work, pls share the full html code to me. U can paste it in pastebin or some other website and share the link to me.

Comment: Did u try adding a `time.sleep` before `folder = driver.find_element_by_link_text('9908')`?

Comment: yes I added `time.sleep(10)` but it gives the same error

Comment: Oh...Then replace `folder = driver.find_element_by_link_text('9908')` with `folder = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('9908')`

Comment: just same error :(
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"9908"}

Comment: Oh...Try this: `folder = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '9908')]")`