# How to do double click on <a> tag using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

I want to **scrape** the data on web site. But I have a problem,
 **I want to click the a tag with double click.**
 Who know about this? If you know this, help me, please.

My code:

```
<a href="#product-lists id='products'">
```

If you know about it, Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: You will need to include more details, like the url of the website your trying to scrape & code that you have tried so far along with the expected output.

Comment: it's not your code! Only the web element

Comment: @webstar, with the input provided.. no we will not be able to answer this question that is why i had asked to include additional details.

Comment: hello, url is security. sorry.

Comment: I think it's no need the URL. only provide the code that double click the a tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Double clicking in python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870528/double-clicking-in-python-selenium)

Comment: @glisten Hello, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
path='//a[@href="{}"]'.format("#product-lists id='products'")
print(path)
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
source = driver.find_element_by_xpath(path)
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.double_click(source).perform()
```

Your href value looks really messed up but to double click an element by their href values use action builder and find the href value with that value.